# How do I read formatted input in Java?

Tags: java, input, io

Suppose my input file contains:

```
3 4 5 6    7        8
9


10
```

I want to run a while loop and read integers, so that I will get 3,4,5,6,7,8 and 10 respectively after each iteration of the loop.

This is really simple to do in C/C++ but not in Java...

I tried this code:

```
try {
            DataInputStream out2 = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));

            int i=out2.read();
            while(i!=-1){
                System.out.println(i);
                i=out2.readInt();
            }

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
```

and what I get is:

```
51
540287029
540418080
538982176
151599117
171511050
218762506
825232650
```

How do I read the integers from this **file** in **Java**?

Comment: FYI: DataInputStream is for reading binary, not text.

Comment: So, did the java solution turn out to be easier than the C++ or harder?

Comment: for me, reading inputs in C is still easier, specially where the file contains all sorts of data - numbers, strings, floats etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One can use the [`Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class and its [`nextInt`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) method:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("3  4        5   6");

while (s.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(s.nextInt());
}
```

Output:

```
3
4
5
6
```

Basically by default, the `Scanner` object will ignore any whitespace, and will get the next token.

The [`Scanner` class as a constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream)) which takes an [`InputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) as the source for the character stream, so one could use a [`FileInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) that opens the source of the text.

Replace the `Scanner` instantiation in the above example with the following:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)));
```