# Reading a formatted text file in java

Tags: java, android, file, text, formatted

I mainly program in C++ and I have been working on porting my game over to Java with Android.
I ran into a short problem with some of my code. 
My text file is in this format:

```
0:1 0:0 1:1 2:2 3:3
```

I read it in with the fscanf function like so:

```
for(int Y = 0;Y < MAP_HEIGHT;Y++) {
    for(int X = 0;X < MAP_WIDTH;X++) {
        Tile tempTile;

        fscanf(FileHandle, "%d:%d ", &tempTile.TileID, &tempTile.TypeID);

        TileList.push_back(tempTile);
    }
```

How would I read in the formatted data shown in Java? Obviously there is no fscanf lol afaik...

Comment: Have you tried the `Scanner` class? Check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414444/how-do-i-read-formatted-input-in-java).

Comment: Looking into that now, thanks.

Comment: Look at this [topic][1]
So you might use Scanner class from java.util

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981232/what-is-the-scanf-equivalent-method-in-java-and-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to format the string in java

```
   import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

         String str="0:1 0:0 1:1 2:2 3:3";
         format(str);
    }

    public static void format(String str) 
    {
        StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(str, " ");  // Use Space as a Token
        while(tokens.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            String token=tokens.nextToken();
            String[] splitWithColon=token.split(":");
            System.out.println(splitWithColon[0] +" "+splitWithColon[1]);
        }

    }

}
```

Output of Code :

```
0 1
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me. The reason is because I'm only interested in the numerical values. The ":" is also a delimiter. Each tile needs this set of values (1:0) excluding the colon. The two numbers that represent a property of that tile. So basically each "2:0" represents an individual tile.

Comment: So basically you want output "1 0" ??

Comment: Kind of, basically

    Tile T = new Tile();
T.prop = 1;
T.type = 0;

Comment: for every tile in the for loops. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code like this:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String str = "0:1 0:0 1:1 2:2 3:3";
        format(str);
    }

    public static void format(String str) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(str);

        while (s.hasNext("(\\d):(\\d)")) {
            MatchResult mr = s.match();
            System.out.println("a=" + mr.group(1) + ";b=" + mr.group(2));
            s.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you use this in a 2 dimensional for loop?